# ffmpeg Merge audio into mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg

For example :
I have an audio file 5 minutes long
And 1 mp4 no audio file is 10 minutes long
I want to use ffmpeg to stitch them together and output a 5 minute mp4 video ( equal to the length of the input audio file )
Thank you

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: could you use FFprobe to get the duration of the audio file, then pass that duration to your FFmpeg convert command via the `-t` option?